# initializing variable while defining function in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, initialization

Learning Python, trying to read NASA program. Why is it show=True while defining function? Are we allowed to initialize variable this way? I don' see any use of it.

```
def visualizeDomain(domain, show=True):
    '''Draw all the sensors and ground truth from a domain'''
    centerMap(domain.center[0], domain.center[1], 11)
    for s in domain.sensor_list:
        apply(addToMap, s.visualize(show=show))
    if domain.ground_truth != None:
        addToMap(domain.ground_truth, {}, 'Ground Truth', False)
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Comment: it's passed to `s.visualize()` on the fourth line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Python's syntax for default arguments. If no value is passed for the second argument to `visualizeDomain()`, it will automatically be assigned a value of `True`. (See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Comment: And note that it *is* evaluated when defining the function, so if the value is mutable and you change it inside the function, the change holds for the next invocation of the function. Doesn't apply in this case since `True` is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, all the answers are right. Basically you can call that function with just one argument... "Show" will just be True.